# How would I acquire a list of correct and uniform contact information for "important Bitcoin people"?

Tags: data-request

I have no money to pay for any lists. I want something like:

```
Some Guy,someguy@gmail.com,1978,USA,male,CEO,https://binero.com/
Some Gal,somegal@yahoo.com,1995,UK,female,CEO,https://coolcoins.com/
...
```

Manually trying to first find all major Bitcoin websites and then trying to find out this info, or even just the e-mail part, is a nightmare. I've tried in the past. They actively hide the info. I didn't manage to compile any useful list.

Is there really no centralized place listing contact information and data for "important people" or "key people" in a given industry/context? I want this for many other things as well, such as "key players in the retro video game community", etc.

I must express that I find it maddeningly frustrating that nothing seems to be available in public. I have no "secret connections" so I never get access to any such "secret lists" and all the good stuff that's kept far away from the public. Sadly, I'm "the public". I just visit endless webpages with garbage/outdated/nonsensical data, or (more often than not) are trying to make me pay them money. I don't have money. It has to be possible without already being rich.

Comment: I think you might be asking questions that are opposed to the architecture of Bitcoin, so may not have an answer. But someone may try and create a central repository ...